# How to develop an iOS app that notifies you even when turned off

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, background-process

I want to develop an iOS application which, while turned off, is able to give you notifications when events happen. I initially thought it would be impossible but I realised that the Gmail app has this feature: even when I turn it off, it will alert me when an email arrives.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: You've answered yourself - use push notifications. Read more here -> https://developer.apple.com/notifications/.

Comment: Can you just clarify what you mean by turned off? If you mean the **Device** is turned off then no this isn't possible. If you just mean the **app** isn't running then yes this is perfectly possible and I'd advice to have a read about Push Notifications